# Passing Value of Drop Down List to a Web Form Email

Tags: c#, forms

I have an inquiry form. One question is a drop down list to select the type of inquiry. The drop down list is populated from a table. I would like to have the value from the InquiryType field in the email, but all I can manage to pass is the INQID.

```
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT InquiryType, Email1, Email2, Email3 FROM [inquiries] WHERE INQID = @INQID";
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@INQID", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InquiryType", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd1.Parameters["@INQID"].Value = DDLInquiry.SelectedValue;
                cmd1.Parameters["@InquiryType"].Value = DDLInquiry.DataValueField;
```

message body formatting

```
MsgBody.AppendLine("Type of Inquiry: " + DDLInquiry.DataValueField);
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Generally your options would be to use the value you want as the actual "value" of the drop-down (so the same value as both the text and the value), or to use the identifier from the selected drop-down value to look up the record you want when handling the form.

Comment: Ah! I was so caught up in what I was doing wrong in the code behind that I completely disregarded the page code. Easy-peasy fix that was making me tear my hair out! Thank you so much!!